# How to change current product cover photo with javascript in PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: javascript, php, html, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to **set customized product preview** (*t-shirt with uploaded logotype*) **as product thumbnail**. It's image, file type: jpeg - I have full url with http: `NEW_PRODUCT_THUMB`.

How to **set this url as product image** / cover / thumbnail?

For tests, I tried to set it with jQuery:

```js
// <section id="main"> , first <img> child element
$('section#main img:eq(0)').attr("src", NEW_PRODUCT_THUMB );
```

**Problem:** Every changes - t-shirt size, color are triggering refresh product page, and then - default image was loaded (from database, not from my customization JS editor).

Here is webpage, where customized product image is set as thumbnail in correct way, but I have no idea how?
https://products.printzware.com/home/114-faded-short-sleeves-tshirt.html#/4-size-one_size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution #1**

Why not editing your `product.tpl` Smarty template file and add a condition stating that if this product has been customized within the current shopping, you display a specific image, instead of the cover one?

You can retrieve the customized image by calling the following method from the `Cart` class:

```
getProductCustomization($id_product, $type = null, $not_in_cart = false)
```

And for the real-time modifications, you can of course keep your jQuery code.

**Solution #2**

Same logic, but instead, you can override the `getImageLink()` method in the `Link` class.

Once your override is ready, you can call it dynamically via an ajax call with jQuery.

This will work even if the page is reloaded.